# Use schedule and a predecessor. together in task

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

Trying to schedule task on 23rd of every month ,after the some particular tasks

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TASK p.pat_t
  WAREHOUSE = W_Simple
  SCHEDULE = 'USING CRON 0 0 23 * * America'
  TIMESTAMP_INPUT_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24'
  after DE_ER
```

** Getting an error ERROR cannot have both a schedule and a predecessor.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's expected: A schedule cannot be specified for child tasks in a DAG.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-task.html#optional-parameters

DAG: A Directed Acyclic Graph (DAG) is a series of tasks composed of a single root task and additional tasks, organized by their dependencies.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tasks-intro.html#label-task-dag

As the predecessor will have a scheduler, why do you need to give a scheduled time for the child task?

Additional info: If the predecessor task is run every day but you want to run your task on only a specific day, you can call an SP (or SQL block) from your task and check the day before running the actual SQL statements. For example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TASK p.pat_t
  WAREHOUSE = W_Simple
  TIMESTAMP_INPUT_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24'
  after DE_ER
  AS
  BEGIN
     IF ( DAY(current_date()) = 23 ) THEN
     -- INSERT ETC
     -- SELECT ETC;
     END IF;
  END;
```

Rohit you need to add SQL statements instead of comments. Here is a sample:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TASK DE_ER
 WAREHOUSE = gokhan_wh
  SCHEDULE = 'USING CRON 0 0 23 * * Europe/Amsterdam'
  as
  select current_Date();

CREATE OR REPLACE TASK pat_t
  WAREHOUSE = gokhan_wh
  TIMESTAMP_INPUT_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24'
  after DE_ER
  AS
  BEGIN
     IF ( DAY(current_date()) = 23 ) THEN
        SELECT CURRENT_DATE();
     END IF;
  END;
```

Comment: Because the DE_ER task runs every day ,but the task which I want to create should run only on 23rd

Comment: So,Once the DE_ER task is completed on that particular day ,then only p.pat_t should run i.e 23rd

Comment: is there is any other way of doing that

Comment: @RohitJha Make your task call a procedure (instead of just one SQL statement), and in that procedure, check the date. If the date is not 23rd, then skip the SQL etc...

Comment: Any approach will help in this one

Comment: Hi @GOKHAN ALI :- I am getting this error while executing "syntax error line 7 at position 13 unexpected '('. (line 7)"

Comment: have you tried to add some real SQL statements instead of comments?

Comment: yes I tried ,while running in the snowflake

Comment: Anything on this ,Still looking out for executing the task

Comment: @RohitJha I think the solution is already there. You should add actual SQLs instead of comments. I will add another sample to answer.